# Why is the New Zealand dollar on parity with the Australian dollar?

Tags: exchange-rates

The New Zealand dollar [has reached parity with the Australian dollar for the first time in more than forty years.](http://www.stuff.co.nz/business/67600087/australian-dollar-parity-party-approaches)

The question is - what are the economic factors that have caused this?